# 'DWORD CHackProcess::GetModuleNamePointer(LPSTR,DWORD)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [11]' to 'LPSTR'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have searched on this site for an answer and the top answer did not work for me, I keep getting this error.  I recently (not sure if I did it successfully) imported my project, that has no errors, from my desktop to my new laptop.  Whenever I try to run, I get this error in multiple files, using only one as an example :

> error C2664: 'DWORD CHackProcess::GetModuleNamePointer(LPSTR,DWORD)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [11]' to 'LPSTR'

This is on these lines:

```
while (__dwordClient == 0x0) __dwordClient = GetModuleNamePointer("client.dll", __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);

while (__dwordEngine == 0x0) __dwordEngine = GetModuleNamePointer("engine.dll"6, __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);

while (__dwordVGui == 0x0) __dwordVGui = GetModuleNamePointer("vguimatsurface.dll", __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230353.aspx) states the following definition for `LPSTR`:

`typedef char* PSTR, *LPSTR;`

This means that it is a non `const` expression. The string you're passing is constant.

You just have to pass a non constant string as the first argument.

EDIT:

It could be translated to the following:

```
char engineModuleName[] = "engine.dll";
GetModuleNamePointer(engineModuleName, __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);
```

Comment: Also, assuming you got that function from [here](https://github.com/CoolOppo/Counter-Strike-Hacks/blob/master/ZTrigger/CProcess.h), I hope you're not planning on cheating online...

Comment: Nah not online just learning.  When you say I have to pass a non const expression, what does this look like?

Comment: @Panda but it is still a weird definition of the function if it is not actually changing the char array in any way.

Comment: This has worked so far, but I have more errors that are basically the same thing. Gonna try and solve these with your previous assistance ill get back to you if i need you again.  Thanks man you're a life saver.

Comment: Also do you know why these errors are only occurring on my laptop and not my desktop?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to make you learn something here and basically the compiler error already said the same thing as me.

Comment: @Panda are you using different compilers? It might be that the compiler implicitly converts it to the same thing as my answer.

Comment: @Panda see [this](http://rextester.com/KNC41373). Here it just allows it. But in my IDE (Visual Studio Enterprise 2017) it doesn't.

Comment: I added what you put with the engine module char adjusted to the other ones it needed and it compiled, however it is just a blank console. **EDIT** Fixed this issue i forgot that I was using x86 functions and had it on x64 mode

Comment: @Panda You're kind of going off-topic with this question. I already answered the original problem you were facing. If you have any more problems I suggest you open up a new question and close this one.

Comment: @Neijwiert: an upvote for encouraging the question author to learn for him/herself, and to stick to one theme per post - good work!